# MySQL query to get SUM from joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `conversions` and `cc_sessions`.

`conversions` has the following columns:

```
session_id (int 11)
cpa (int 11)
revenue (int 11)
```

`cc_sessions` has the following columns:

```
call_session_id (int 11)
agent (int 5)
```

The two tables are related by `session_id` and `call_session_id`.

Here's what I'm trying to get from the query:

sum of all `cpa` associated with an individual `agent` whenever the `cpa > 0` and `revenue = 0`

So essentially if agent 17 had 20 conversions where there was no revenue but there was a cpa of 10 I should see a row:

```
agent sum(cpa)
17     200
```

Here's what I've tried but it is definitely not working right:

```
SELECT s.agent, SUM(c.cpa)
FROM edu.conversions c JOIN edu.cc_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.call_session_id 
WHERE c.revenue = '0' AND c.cpa > '0'
```

Comment: Can you explain again what you're looking for? Do you want to sum the cpa? Do you want to count how many rows have a cpa > 0 and no revenue? Why is your expected value 200, I can't piece it all together.

Comment: Ya sorry it is a bit confusing. I want a sum of all the CPA values connected to individual agents whenever the CPA is > 0 and revenue = 0. In my example agent number 17 had 20 conversions where cpa = 10 for each and revenue = 0. So in that example agent 17 would have sum(cpa) = 200

Comment: Did you try the query I answered with? I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this in MySql. This is how it would work in SQL:

```
SELECT s.agent, SUM(c.cpa)
FROM edu.conversions c
JOIN edu.cc_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.call_session_id
WHERE c.revenue = '0'
AND c.cpa > '0'
GROUP BY s.agent
```

Since your columns are `INT`'s, perhaps this works better:

```
SELECT s.agent, SUM(c.cpa)
FROM edu.conversions c
JOIN edu.cc_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.call_session_id
WHERE c.revenue = 0
AND c.cpa > 0
GROUP BY s.agent
```

Comment: This seems to work in a development environment however it's not working in production for me... Clearly I have something else not working right but I'm going to accept this answer as it does work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum something per agent, you'll need to group by agents. Your conditions can stay in there where clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.agent, SUM(c.cpa)
FROM conversion c JOIN cc_sessions s ON s.call_session_id = c.session_id
WHERE c.revenue = 0 AND c.cpa > 0
GROUP BY s.agent;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eea2c3/1) example.

Comment: Yes this query will also work but it's the same one that programmer 43229 gave so I picked his answer first.

Comment: @ajax1515 you said his query isn't working for you though. What's the problem you are having?

Comment: The query itself works which answers my question... The statement I made was more in frustration as now that I have a working query I'm finding other problems in my program... If I need to I will ask a new question regarding those issues but more testing and debugging is needed before I get to that point. Thank you for the help @McAdam331

Comment: Oh, understood. Feel free to notify me anytime you need help!